# Angular: return type string into catchError but have HTTP with different type

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a problem with the return type in my Observable. In my service, when I try to get the string into the `catchError`, I have an error with the return type of my `foo()` method.

*service.ts*

```
foo(): Observable<string> { <=== PROBLEM HERE
  return this.httpService
    .postSomething()
    .pipe(
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        return of('Error');
      })
    );
}
```

*httpService.ts*

```
postSomething(): Observable<ObjModel> {
  return this.httpClient.request('post', 'url', {body});
}
```

Error say:

```
foo(): Observable<string | ObjModel> {
```

The problem is that I want to **return only a string**, otherwise my implementation of `foo()` returns an error telling me that it expects a **string or an objModel**.

Thank your for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `foo()` has to manage 2 different cases

1. No error occurs in http call and therefore it returns whatever is returned by `postSomething()`, which you declare to be an `Observable<ObjModel>`
2. An error occurs in http call and therefore it returns what you have coded within `catchError` i.e. an `Observable<string>` since you return `of('Error') which is exactly an`Observable`emitting a`string`

Therefore `foo()` can return either an `Observable<ObjModel>` or an `Observable<strince>`, i.e. it returns an `Observable<string | ObjModel>`. This is the reason why the compiler complains.

Comment: how to handle this case ? i mean when foo() can return either X or Y,

Comment: You can specify that `foo()` returns `Observable<string | ObjModel>` or just let Typescript figure it out via type inference

Comment: This is fine, however, my issue is coming when i want to eventually use only Observable<ObjModel> as string case i am handling in catchError, and returning empty ObjModel. The linting error does not comes if i use of (null) in my catchError return.

Comment: private getSomeStuff(): Observable<PagedResult<ObjModel>> {
    return this.jobService.getAll(OpenApiUtilsService.generateQuery())
      .pipe(catchError((error: JobsApiError) => {
        this.handleError(error);
        const emptyObjModel: ObjModel[] = [];
        return of({
          totalCount: 0,
          items: emptyObjModel,
        } as PagedResult<ObjModel>);
      }));
  }  getAll basically returns Observable<PagedResult<ObjModel> |  SomeErrorObject> , so i want to make sure that getSomeStuff only returns PagedResult<ObjModel> as  SomeErrorObject is handled in catchError

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if there will be no error, it will not call `catchError` and will return actually `Observable<ObjModel>`. So you need also to handle that case.

Answer (score 0):

if there is no error, your foo() function will return

```
Observable<ObjModel>
```

type, so you can't declare foo() function to return

```
foo(): Observable<string>
```

type.